# Use <span> in Redactor

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

Is there any way to add `<span>` tags to Redactor II or the Redactor I plugin - would like to upgrade a site to latest version of Craft which had Redactor I and the https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft plugin.

The site has some tags like `<span class="blue-color">` etc.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Craft filters out `<span>` tags by default.

You can control this in two ways:

1. By disabling the "*Clean up HTML*" setting applied to the custom field

   [image]
2. For more control, you can create your own custom redactor config JSON file. It's discussed in the docs here:
   https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs