# Prevent Redactor from stripping tags like <span>

Tags: craft3, redactor, json

Is there any possible way to prevent `<span>` tags from being stripped from a Redactor field? I've tried all I can using custom Redactor and HTMLPurifier configs to no avail.

Basically what I'm trying to do long-term is replace heading tags like `<h2>` and `<h3>` with `<span>`  and then apply the same styling as the heading tags, perhaps by applying classes to the `<span>`s and going from there.

Things I've tried to no avail:

- Added "allowedTags" rule to Redactor config
- Added "HTML.Allowed" rule to HTML Purifier config
- Disabled HTML Purfier for field altogether
- Added `"paragraphize": false` to Redactor config

The only resource I've found regarding this is [this question from 3 years ago](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/use-span-in-redactor). Haven't had any luck with those suggestions either.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not with Redactor, but...

You can do this with the [Retcon (Craft CMS Plugin)](https://plugins.craftcms.com/retcon?craft4).

Convert all `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags to `<span>`.

Code example:

```
{{ entry.redactorField | retconChange( [ 'h2', 'h3' ], 'span' ) }}
```

See [Recton Docs](https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft) (GitHub) for more details.